# Can't modify array because of for loop in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've been struggling with this all day, it doesn't seem to make any sense because I have very similar code that is working fine. I've tried everything, I've tried making a separate method that returns a string array, but none of it has worked. Every time, the postIDs array is set to null when accessed outside of the bracket followed by the parentheses (after the line reading "print(self.postIDs)"). Thanks for any help you could give me.

```
var postIDs = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self        

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("saved").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        var ids = [String]()

        let saved = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        for (elem, _) in saved {
            ids.append(elem)
        }
        self.postIDs = ids
        print(self.postIDs) // returns the values I would expect
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

    guard self.postIDs.count >= 1 else {return} // postIDs count is equal to 0 here, and when I print postIDs the result is []
```

Comment: The reason is the block of code inside `observeSingleEvent` is not in the same thread with the rest of your function. The rest is in main thread while `observeSingleEvent` is running in background. They are asynchronous. You need to get `postIDs` after your data is completed loaded.

Comment: the statement where you get the expected values is inside a closure. this results in a delayed execution for the closure block. you can either try to check if a completion handler can be implemented or else you should do the required stuff with array inside the closure itself.

Comment: Put breakpoints inside and outside the block `observeSingleEvent` and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is because

```
ref.child("users").child(uid).child("saved").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    var ids = [String]()

    let saved = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
    for (elem, _) in saved {
        ids.append(elem)
    }
    self.postIDs = ids
    print(self.postIDs) // returns the values I would expect
})
```

works on background and other line of code executes before the callback came

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        usersTableView.dataSource = self
        usersTableView.delegate = self
//        getSnapShot()


        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Users").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.exists() {
                self.postData = snapshot.value! as! [String : AnyObject]
                self.postData.removeValue(forKey: self.appDelegate.KeyValue)
//                self.getUserNames(Snapshot: self.postData)
            }
            else{
                print("No users")
            }
            print(self.postData) //Does not  return nil
            self.getSnapShot() //Take snapshot outside paranthesis
        })

        print(self.postData) //Returns nil
    }


    func getSnapShot() {

       print(self.postData) //Value of Snapshot is printed

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, I'll try implementing this now.